# How to get text that is not in the source list to alert using jquery autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Given this example, http://jsfiddle.net/CezarisLT/KHqQm/

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
   <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
   <input id="tags" />
 </div>

 $(function() {
                var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"];
   $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
                                 source: availableTags,
                                 select: function( event, ui ) {
                                  }
    });
  });
```

How do I get text that is not in the autocomplete source list to alert after hitting the enter key? For example, if I typed in "hello world" in the text area, which is not in the list of options, how can I get hello world to alert after hitting the enter key?

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but maybe it's [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/KHqQm/1/) ....

Comment: thanks for understanding my question, and yes, that is what I'm looking for

Comment: Added it as an answer, was'nt sure if I got the question or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event handler to check for keys pressed in the input, and on enter key, alert the inputs value:

```
$( "#tags" ).on('keyup', function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) alert(this.value);
  }).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      select: function( event, ui ) {

      }
});
```